# How to suppress JSLint warnings in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, jslint

I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have installed JSLint and Web-Essentials as well. After running JsLint on my javascript file, it is giving me a warning repetitively. I want to hide that warning. How can I hide the warning?

I thought it should be straight forward, but unable to figure out.

[image]

Comment: Are you using "JSLint.NET for Visual Studio" or "JSLint.NET for MSBuild (from NuGet)"?

Comment: @ruffin I am using "JSLint.NET for Visual Studio"

Comment: Great; thanks! I think that's got it. There will probably be other errors (I just "corrected"/told JSLint to tolerate the one you had highlighted), but I think you get the point. ;^) That right-click was hidden a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the latest version. One hitch over the older version of JSLint.NET: You have to right click the *project* to access JSLint.NET Project Settings, like so...

[image: context menu with jslint.net project settings]

Now you can select the "messy whitespace" option to turn that "JSLint directive" on globally.

[image: JSLint.NET Settings pane]]

You can also solve this file-by-file by putting `/*jslint white */` at the top.

```
/*jslint white */
function spam()  {
    "use strict";
    return    5;
}
```

From the errors you're seeing, it looks like you have a relatively recent version of JSLint. Check over the [instructions page at JSLint](http://jslint.com/help.html) for what all the rest of the options mean.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations make it difficult to improve the answer. Let me know what's wrong, and I'll see if I can't figure out something better!